# Rails 7 | ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken after Successfull Payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, ruby-on-rails-7

I have integrated a payment gateway via Easebuzz, so far so good,The success URL is a POST request to orders#successE (ControllerName#MethodName), after successfull payment, when it is calling successE POST request, i am getting:
[image]

this is the code:

```
def payE
                @payment_response = Easebuzz::Payment.initiate({
                  "txnid" => "#{@order.id}",
                  "amount" => amount.to_f,
                  "firstname" => current_user.name,
                  "email" => current_user.email,
                  "phone" => current_user.phone_number,
                  "surl" => "http://localhost:3000/orders/#{@order.id}/successE",
                  "furl" => "http://localhost:3000/response.php",
                  "address1" => address,
                  "country" => "India",
                  #"zipcode" => "123123"
                })
        
                if @payment_response['status'] == 1
                  data = @payment_response['data']
                  redirect_to("https://testpay.easebuzz.in/pay/#{data}", allow_other_host: true, status: 303)
                end
end
```

how can i fix this issue? :')

can someone explain what is happening in simple words? is it trying to verify CSRF Token but it cannot
because a null is returned? please insert some new knowledge into my brain :- ) i would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby on Rails is unable to verify the authenticity token on this controller method, because the callback from the external application does support and doesn't send the expected token.

To disable the authenticity token only on this specific controller method, add this code to your controller:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:successE]
```

Read more about [Rails' RequestForgeryProtection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection.html).

Comment: so the external application (Easebuzz in this case) does not send expected token and its all their work for the security? so is it safe for me to use `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:successE]` in production??

Comment: Yes it is safe, because in this setup (external service not sending the token) this check is expected to fail and therefore will only work when the check is disabled. Context: For normal form requests, the server sends a token with the form that the browser has to return with the filled form on the next request. This technique obviously doesn't when the external server sends POST request without forms, session, and cookie being involved.

Comment: thanks alot brother, i learnt new things today!